# submap a period of time

Tags: java, jodatime

I'm making a info graph of my emails.
It goes quite well but things are more confusing then they have to be, for example if i want to get the amount of emails someone sended me in a month then i use this:

```
for (Person p : AL_persons) {
  for (int y = firstYear; y <= lastYear; y++) {
    for (int m = 1; m <= 12; m++) {
      ArrayList<Email> emailThatMonth = new ArrayList<Email>();
      for (Email e : p.emails) {
        if (e.date.year().get() == y
          && e.date.monthOfYear().get() == m) {
          emailThatMonth.add(e);
        }
      }
      if (emailThatMonth.size() > maxEmailsMonth)
        maxEmailsMonth = emailThatMonth.size();
    }
  }
}
```

I want to improve that so i can get it far more easy,
I was thinking of storing the first day of every month, so i can re use that.
(not tested code from here on)

```
  ArrayList<DateTime> monthStarts = new ArrayList<DateTime>();

  for (int y = firstYear; y <= lastYear; y++) {
    for (int m = 1; m <= 12; m++) {
      monthStarts.add(new LocalDate(y+"-"+m+"-01"));
    }
  }
```

Then to get the emails i could use a submap:

```
  for(DateTime ld : monthStarts) {
    ArrayList<Email> emailThatMonth = emails.submap(ld, ld.plusMonths(1));
  }
```

I think this should work, however it's quite some work (not that i mind that), i just wanted to know what you guys think of it, to see if someone has tips or other ideas to deal with it.

note, i use joda time (and i love it)

Comment: So... what information are you trying to get?  The number of emails for each month?  The most emails received in any given month?  It looks like you end up writing a lot of variables that are never read before they go out of scope.

Comment: I have a arrayList persons, a person holds an arrayList with all emails from that person. I want to get the total emails in periods of a month per person.
I also have a arrayList that hold's all emails from all persons, so there i want to get all emails from a month (all persons).

Answer (score 0):

The current first part looks through all the emails for each person 12*numyears times.  You can simplify to only go through them once by finding the month on each email and incrementing different counters as you go.  I have not tested this code since I am unsure about some specifics in your class structure.

```
HashMap<Person,HashMap<String,Integer>> hm = new HashMap<Person,HashMap<String,Integer>>();  
for (Person p : all_persons) 
{
  HashMap<String,Integer> tempMap = new HashMap<String,Integer>();
  for (Email e : p.emails) 
  {
    String tag = e.date.year().get() + "-" + e.date.monthOfYear().get();
    int lastvalue = tempMap.get(tag); 
    tempMap.put(tag, lastvalue+1);
  }
  hm.put(p,tempMap);
}
```

So for the second part(search for all emails from a given month), we take much the same approach.  Iterate through once and add all matches to your new list.

```
String targetMonth = "2012-01";//or whatever month you're looking for
ArrayList<Email> emailThatMonth = new ArrayList<Email>();
for (Email e: emails)
{
    String tag = e.date.year().get() + "-" + e.date.monthOfYear().get();
    if (tag.compareToIgnoreCase(targetMonth) == 0)
      emailThatMonth.add(e);      
}
```

Comment: Can you explain the adventage over mine?
Also i noticed that i used localDate so that was a quite bad idea of me since i could have several emails on the same day and localDate doesn't have hours etc. But i can change that to dateTime.

Comment: In the first one you go through each person's email list a bunch of times, 4 nested loops.  Goes through each person's list 1 time, 2 nested loops.  It also provides the historical record, the only variable that doesn't fall out of scope in your example is the max for 1 month, while you said you wanted the number for each month.